# Tensorflow KerasRegressor - reading the setting 'verbose=2' output correctly

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, verbose

```
...
Epoch 7/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 84.1231
Epoch 8/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 65.1705
Epoch 9/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 53.3347
Epoch 10/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 45.4169
**11/11 - 0s - loss: 15.8337**
Epoch 1/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 611.2643
Epoch 2/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 563.0521
Epoch 3/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 460.6799
Epoch 4/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 330.3016
Epoch 5/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 215.1095
Epoch 6/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 137.6284
Epoch 7/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 93.3648
Epoch 8/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 69.6211
Epoch 9/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 55.6200
Epoch 10/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 46.7145
**11/11 - 0s - loss: 19.7976**
Epoch 1/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 533.4615
Epoch 2/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 510.9247
Epoch 3/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 459.0772
Epoch 4/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 368.3991
Epoch 5/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 259.9857
Epoch 6/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 168.8091
Epoch 7/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 108.7919
Epoch 8/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 74.7730
Epoch 9/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 56.3438
Epoch 10/10
91/91 - 0s - loss: 46.0458
**11/11 - 0s - loss: 107.8788**
...
```

I'm running Tensorflow KerasRegressor with 'verbose=2'. I understand most of the output except for the  lines enclosed in **. It shows up after all epochs are executed and always has a weird amount of loss. I first thought is the average loss from all epochs, but it's apparently not.

Can anyone please elaborate. Thank you! :)

Here's the code:

```
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# load dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/housing.data'
df = pandas.read_csv(url, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
dataset = df.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:13]
Y = dataset[:,13]

# define base model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

%%time
# evaluate model with standardized dataset
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=10, batch_size=5, verbose=2)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Standardized: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Here's the link to GoogleColab code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b8YUV4ZWMizrF5-kWRMJkiZYqu-iToGx?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show us following code...

Comment: My guess is that that is validation loss, but its unclear to me how cross_val_score calls the estimators' fit function

Comment: I guess it's something to do with the ```kfold = KFold(n_splits=2)```. It shows up in the end of each split, but why the loss value is so off each time...

Comment: If it is the validation loss it is expected to not be exactly the same as training loss. Reasons for this are over/underfit or the size of the test set being smaller so not statistically the same as the training set. See for instance [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/keras-difference-beetween-val-loss-and-loss-during-training).

Comment: Please include code in the question itself, not as an external link.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the validation loss. `cross_val_score` calls the estimator's default scorer when not provided a score argument (see [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)). The [score function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasRegressor#score) for a Keras regressor returns the test loss, and likely is printing it at verbosity=2. This function is just calling model.evaluate() which will act like you've seen at verbosity=2.

As mentioned in the comment test/validation loss isn't expected to generally be the same as the training loss for various reason. Overfit/underfit can make the model perform differently on the data seen during training compared to unseen data. Also, the smaller size of the test set may mean that it does not look the same as the training set so will have a different fitting score. See for instance [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/keras-difference-beetween-val-loss-and-loss-during-training).

Comment: Yes, but the difference can be completely off, like 11.6414 and 97.7314 for instance. Isn't it too much.